# I was triying to load the recycler view in my home fragment but somehow it is not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am recieving this from the console-
**I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/ample.photoblo: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)**

I am very new with recycler view and I researched and found out it has something to do with memory leaks which happen when you inflate recycler view with fragments

Can someone help me resolve this issue.

Here is my HomeFragment.java Code:

```
package com.example.photoblog;


import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView blog_view;
    private List<BlogPost> blog_list;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private Adapter adapter;
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        blog_list=new ArrayList<>();
        blog_view=view.findViewById(R.id.blog_view);
        firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        adapter=new Adapter(blog_list);
        blog_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        blog_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                for(DocumentChange doc: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
                {
                    if(doc.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)
                    {
                        BlogPost blogPost=doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);
                        blog_list.add(blogPost);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        adapter=null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And My adapter code:

```
package com.example.photoblog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<BlogPost> blog_list;
    public Adapter(List<BlogPost> blog_list)
    {
      this.blog_list=blog_list;
    }
    private Context context;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item,parent,false);
        context=parent.getContext();
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String desc=blog_list.get(position).getDescription();
        holder.setDesc(desc);
        String image_url=blog_list.get(position).getImage_url();
        holder.setImage(image_url);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blog_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        private TextView blogdesc;
        private ImageView blogimage;

        private View mView;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
        }
        public void setDesc(String text)
        {
            blogdesc=mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_description);
            blogdesc.setText(text);
        }
        public void setImage(String image_url)
        {
            blogimage=mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_postimg);
            Glide.with(context).load(image_url).into(blogimage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide  your adapter code as well

Comment: call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after the for loop is done. Not everytime you add an item.